# String cannot convert to json

Tags: php, android

I am new to php, I develop android to php web services which is work fine in local host. I want to make my app live so I uploaded my php files in `byethost17.com` in browser, it works fine return json but when I run my app its show

```
org.json.JSONException: Value  script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`
```

The code works fine with json parsing from local host, the problem is from   free hosting website. What is solution? Is there any good free web hosting sites? 100% free???

```
   org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type   
  java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
 at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)






        this is result from  browser  when hit same url

    {"data":[{"Category":  
 {"Category_ID":"3","Category_name":"Camera","Category_image":
 "upload\/images\/7089-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":
{"Category_ID":"9","Category_name":"Cars",
"Category_image":"upload\/images\/7789-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category": 
{"Category_ID":"4","Category_name":"Clothes",
 "Category_image":"upload\/images\/9350-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":
{"Category_ID":"1","Category_name":"Computer",
  "Category_image":"upload\/images\/1843-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":
{"Category_ID":"7","Category_name":"Music",
"Category_image":"upload\/images\/8666-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":
{"Category_ID":"5","Category_name":"Other",
"Category_image":"upload\/images\/6260-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":
 {"Category_ID":"2","Category_name":"Smartphone",

 "Category_image":"upload\/images\/3025-2015-07-09.png"}},{"Category":
{"Category_ID":"8","Category_name":"Sports",

   "Category_image":"upload\/images\/5354-2015-07-09.png"}},

{"Category":{"Category_ID":"10","Category_name":"waqas 
Company","Category_image":"upload\/images\/9853-2016-04-11.jpg"}}]}
```

Comment: What string are you trying to convert to JSON?

Comment: its online store product data   i found this qurstion similar to my problem   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439515/problems-in-parse-com-php-hosting

Comment: can any one tell me free hosting sites who give me correct json????????

Comment: what json you are trying to acquire? update the json string in the question. and the data you are getting in android is surely not json post your php code as well. you can use hostinger.com or 2freehosting.com I am sure about these because I've already used json on these sites

Comment: akshay kulkami u there???

Comment: thanx men   hostinger.com   this  site is good now my code working fine  thnx alot u help me i  waste my 2 days for finding this issue and solving but no one help me  ur great

Answer (score 0):

The json string you are showing starts with a JSON Array not a JSON Object, try to parse it into an array instead

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get Text of the page, not source.

Because in source, the free hosts put their ad affiliates.

So if you get

```
{"data": "stuff"}
```

In page body, the source would be something like this:

```
<html><head>
    <script>
        /** affliate code **/
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>{"data": "stuff"}</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope you understand...

*(also check the return value of your page source before parsing to JSON)*